# About how old was Abel, when his brother Cain murdered him? Genesis 4:8

Tags: genesis

Genesis 4:8  (NRSV)

> 8 "Cain said to his brother Abel, “Let us go out to the field.”And
>   when they were in the field, Cain rose up against his brother Abel,
>   and killed him."

Comment: @NigelJ In the wider text there are details.

Answer (score 1):

The text doesn't give exact dates either for Abel's birth nor his death. We don't know when Cain or Abel were born, probably shortly after the fall. By the time of Abel's murder they were both men of working age.

> Genesis 4:1-2: Adam made love to his wife Eve, and she became pregnant and gave birth to Cain. She said, “With the help of the Lord I have brought forth a man.” 2 Later she gave birth to his brother Abel. Now Abel kept flocks, and Cain worked the soil.

However the fact that Seth is described and named in remembrance of Abel lets us infer that his death was a short time before Adam's 130th year.

> Genesis 4:25 Adam made love to his wife again, and she gave birth to a son and named him Seth, saying, “God has granted me another child in place of Abel, since Cain killed him.”
>
> Genesis 5:3 When Adam had lived 130 years, he had a son in his own likeness, in his own image; and he named him Seth.

Comment: The [Samaritan Pentateuch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samaritan_Pentateuch) and the [Greek Septuagint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septuagint) have 230 instead of 130, but this is the only Biblical answer.